# Swift: Setting location of popover to center of screen

Tags: ios, swift

```
    var vc = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    var controller = vc.popoverPresentationController

    vc.preferredContentSize=CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 200)
    vc.view.bounds = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 10, height: 10)
```

I'm trying to set the location of my popover to center of device, how do I do this, I basically am just trying to figure out by the autofinder after you press ".".

Right now, the last statement in my code doesn't do anything.
[image]

Comment: Can you formulate your question a bit better? Are you using Autolayout? From the code im seeing it looks like you are performing a segue and trying to change to destinationViewController UIView from the prepareSegue of the sourceViewController

Answer (score 1):

In your case as you want to show the Popover from a `UIButton` you need to set the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` properties.

> A `UIView` in the interface, along with the `CGRect` in that view’s coordinate system, with which the popover should be associated. The popover’s arrow will point to this rect. Typically, the sourceView will be the view that was tapped in order to summon the popover, and the sourceRect will be its bounds.

So you need a code like this:

```
@IBAction func showPopover(sender: AnyObject) {

   var popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIdentifier") as! UIViewController

   popoverContent.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
   var popover = popoverContent.popoverPresentationController

   if let popover = popoverContent.popoverPresentationController {

      let viewForSource = sender as! UIView
      popover.sourceView = viewForSource

      // the position of the popover where it's showed
      popover.sourceRect = viewForSource.bounds

      // the size you want to display
      popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,500)
      popover.delegate = self
   }            

   self.presentViewController(popoverContent, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In case you have working with popover segues you can configure it manually in your `prepareForSegue` as above, something like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MyPopover" {
        let dest = segue.destinationViewController
        if let pop = dest.popoverPresentationController {
            pop.delegate = self

            // set the rest of the properties as above
        }           
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.